# Two ways to find the number of arrangements of MISSISSIPPI such that $S$'s are not placed next to each other?

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

In how many arrangements of **MISSISSIPPI** the $S$'s are not placed next to each other?

Assume we only have the word **MIIIPPI**,there are $8$ places for which a **S** can be placed in,on the other hand there are permutations of the first word,follows the number of such arrangements is :$$\binom{8}{4}\frac{7!}{2!\cdot4!}$$

I tried to use another method,the number of such arrangements is the total arrangements minus the number of the arrangements for which such $S$ are all consecutive,so :
$$\frac{11!}{4!4!2!}-8\frac{7!}{4!2!}$$

But the answers are not the same,so where was I wrong?

Comment: The second method also counts cases where *some* **S** are next to each other, but not in the form **SSSS**, for example, **MISSISSIPPI**.

Comment: "*For which such $S$ are* **all consecutive**"  But... what about arrangements such as `MISSISSIPPI` itself where the S's are *not* all consecutive but still have at least one S placed next to another S?

Comment: Yes, and that thinking covers the case of the S's all appearing *in the same single box* only and misses cases where there were two more more boxes for the S's but still more than one S in at least one of the boxes.

Comment: Consider the following related question... find the number of arrangements of `ABBBBBBB` such that no B's are adjacent.  Using your approach for the second case, you might have said there were $8-2=6$ such arrangements... that you looked at all arrangements and removed only `ABBBBBBB` and `BBBBBBBA` from the count.  However you did not remove `BABBBBBB` or `BBABBBBB` or `BBBABBBB` or any of the others from the count... It should have been clear that no arrangement of seven B's and one A result in no B's being adjacent.

Comment: Yes the way you have done is simpler otherwise you have to count all cases of $2, 3, 4 S$ together and then subtract. More work!

Comment: Then you haven't understood the other way correctly yet.  What specific step do you have doubts about?  The method used is a quintessential approach and you should take the time to truly understand it.

Comment: @MathLover "*Is simpler*"  I disagree with that sentiment.  Try actually going through with it and you'll run into issues such as counting $MIII\color{green}{S}PP\color{blue}{S}\color{red}{SS}$ different than $MIII\color{blue}{S}PP\color{red}{SS}\color{green}{S}$.  If you were to approach like this, you will still have to eventually deal with utilizing gaps between non-S letters if you want to avoid mistakes and this does not generalize well at all... devolving into case-hell.

Comment: @JMoravitz I am talking about the first approach being simpler for this question where he is putting 4 $S$ in $4$ of the $8$ places.

Comment: @MathLover "*I tried to use another method...*" "*the other way is complicated...*" implies to me that the first method mentioned was the book's or teacher's and that the second approach was the OP's attempt.

Comment: @ 45465 Oh, I understand your thought process and yes you could theoretically calculate it as such using your $|A_4|,|A_3|,$ etc...  however this is hugely prone to mistake and the act of calculating these (*except for the case of $|A_4|$ which you made this mistake of ignoring the existence of all the rest in your attempt shown in the question*) will have the same challenges associated with it that the original problem had so you did not succeed in making this any easier, only harder.

Comment: @JMoravitz I think there is confusion. I still read his comment "the other way is complicated" is to your explanations. I think he finally understood and he is referring to "other way" as the second method. That is how I read it and hence my comment. Anyway, will let OP clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The first part is fine. We have
\begin{align*}
\binom{8}{4}\frac{7!}{4!2!1!}=\color{blue}{7\,350}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
The number of all different words which can be built from the letters in $MISSISSIPPI$ is
\begin{align*}
\frac{11!}{4!4!2!1!}=34\,650\tag{2}
\end{align*}
From these words we have to subtract the words which contain consecutive $S$. We consider the $8$ positions where we can place the $4$ S.

\begin{align*}
\,_{1}\,M\,_{2}\,I\,_{3}\,I\,_{4}\,I\,_{5}\,P\,_{6}\,P\,_{7}\,I\,_{8}:
\end{align*}

We have the following ways to group $4$ S with the following number of placements per group
\begin{align*}
&(1,1,1,1)&&(S,S,S,S)\\
&(1,1,2)&&(S,S,SS)\ \ \to3\\
&(2,2)&&(SS,SS)\ \ \ \ \to1\\
&(1,3)&&(S,SSS)\ \ \ \ \to2\\
&(1)&&(SSSS)\ \ \ \ \ \ \to1
\end{align*}
Since only the first group $(1,1,1,1)$ representing $4$ S-runs of length $1$ is admissible, we have to subtract from (2) the number of words built from the other groups.

- The size of the group: $|(S,S,SS)|=3$ for instance. So, we have $\binom{8}{3}$ ways to place the members of the group and $3$ different ways to arrange the three members within a placement.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> &\frac{11!}{4!4!2!1!}-\frac{7!}{4!2!1!}\left(3\binom{8}{3}
> +\binom{8}{2}+2\binom{8}{2}+\binom{8}{1}\right)\\
> &\qquad=34\,650-105\left(56\cdot3+28\cdot1+28\cdot2+8\cdot 1\right)\\
> &\qquad=34\,650 -26\,670\\
> &\qquad\,\,\color{blue}{=7\,350}
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with (1).

Comment: @45465: You're welcome, and thanks for pointing at the typo. I've fixed it  and added some info. The group $(S,S,S,S)$ represents the words with $4$ S and no two are adjacent.